# Is the velocity variable in the conservation of momentum equation always relative to the ground?

Tags: reference-frames, momentum, velocity

I haven't found anything written about this explicitly but from the questions I have done this seems to be the case. Is the velocity in $m_1v_1=m_2v_2$ always relative to the ground (or at least always relative to the same object)? It can't be the relative velocity to each other?

Comment: I think there is an error in the last part of your first sentence. Please correct it.

Comment: Conservation of momentum holds in any and every frame, but all velocities are computed in the *same* frame.

Answer (score 2):

This law holds true for any inertial frame. Thus the velocity referred here, can be with respect to any inertial frame. The momentum conservation law states:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N m_i u_i = \sum_{i=1}^N m_i v_i$$

where, the subscript $i$ stands for $i$-th particle. $N$ is the total number of particles. $m_i$ is the mass of the $i$-th particle. $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the initial and final velocity of the $i$-th particle. As long as you are in an inertial frame with respect to these particles, the law holds true. Thus clearly, the velocities are not necessarily measured with respect to ground only.

**EDIR:** Please note that, as @zerothehero mentioned, all the velocities must be measured with respect to the same inertial frame.